# Paypal flow URL approach in classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, payflowpro

We are using old SDK payflow approach for online payment transactions but on the new server window 2012 we are having problem with the current code so decided to move URL approach for paypal credit card payment. Please help me how to start that. It would be good if you give me some example code. I am using Classic ASP for programming language.

Comment: I'm not sure there's anyone on here who could offer you any more advice other than to just google something like "paypal classic asp integration"

Comment: This isn't how StackOverflow works. *You* need to give *us* the code you've tried, not the other way around.